# Does Batman use makeup or UV sunblock?

Tags: dc, batman

Prompted by this meme:

[image: Meme showing Batman with tanned areas where the mask wouldn't cover him]

I don't think it would work. I'm pretty sure Batman uses makeup and/or protection for his exposed skin that would block UV/radiation, the likes.

However, I can't pinpoint a **canonical** source (preferably from comics, but movie & other media also applies).

Does Batman wear makeup or UV sunblock?

Comment: I thought he was mostly out as batman in night

Comment: Why would he need sunblock when Gotham blocks it for him all the time #CloudyGotham

Comment: In many of the movies, including the Christopher Nolan ones, you can see the area around his eyes while dressed as Batman is also black because he applies makeup.

Comment: Alfred doesn't carry sunblock; http://2.bp.blogspot.com/vr97NWR4rSH8Sr9UQaGziDVMEhJZCFan3I63XVitmrVA8AUXzX5gj9kmR4IqcUAQHh2xqP8g_Ht6=s1600

Answer (score 15):

Since many depictions of [Gotham City](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71574/does-it-always-rain-in-gotham) show it having a near-constant cloud cover and Batman's preferred working time is the night shift, he wouldn't need much sun screen.

I mean, the [Bat Signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bat-Signal), his famous call sign, would only work in a cloudy night.

Comment: What about the makeup?

Comment: There's plenty of instances of Batman appearing in the daytime in the comics, the Adam West series, etc.

Comment: If Batman really needed too, he'd put on the inverse Batman mask and use a tanning lamp.

Comment: In other words, he uses about 5.9 sextillion tons of sunblock.  Called "Planet Earth".

Comment: @Lexible True. Especially the Adam West Batman would probably have his own brand of Bat Sunscreen™ on. If he's prepared for [sharks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QnFOs7QlJSI), he's probably prepared for a little sun.

Comment: @Kakturus Ok (a) I cannot believe they stretched that out over one and a half minutes, (b) why Robin felt the need for the knee-hang hand off is beyond me, and (c) I *love* that the shark exploded when it it hit the water.

Comment: @Mindwin Makeup IS pretty easy to remove though. He just needs some Bad Wipes in his Utility Belt. Also, I doubt a billionaire that's known to be eccentric would raise a lot of questions for some traces of eye shadow. It's probably a sex thing...